# Looking for a Static Code Analysis Tool For Concurrency in .NET like CheckThread for java

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am implementing a concurrent .NET data structures in c# (like `ConcurrentDictionary`, `BlockcingCollection` etc.). It's not about just not forgetting to lock an object when accessing from different threads. It requires sophisticated locking strategies to maximize parallel execution time.

I know there is a tool, a kind of framework for systematic concurrency testing for .NET named [CHESS](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/).

**Question**: Is there also a tool which will find concurrency / threading issues through static code analyses? Something like [CheckThread](http://www.checkthread.org/index.html) which is for java.

Comment: I have 2 "not constructive" - close votes. If one will comment please, it would help me to understand what's wrong on my question.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inspector-xe/ for checking for concurrency issues at runtime... and there's a static analyser but that's for C++.

Comment: Thanks @colinsmith . Why don't you add some text, information, experience you have on the tool and make an answer out of it?

Comment: Also if you're using WinDBG, and your program is getting into a deadlock situation, you can use a deadlock detector via the SOSEX plugin. http://stevestechspot.com/ ....  Example use: http://blog.scriptico.com/04/debugging-with-windbg-deadlocks-in-applications/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a set of resources to help with concurrent programming...they are a mixture of static and runtime based tools.

### Intel Inspector XE/Parallel Studio

Intel do some tools inside Parallel Studio that help with concurrent development, however their Parallel Advisor is only for C/C++.

But for C# you can do runtime thread checking with their Inspector XE (formerly Intel Thread Checker)

- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inspector-xe/.

---

### PRESharp (Microsoft Center for Software Excellence)

There appears to be something called PRESharp mentioned here:

- http://www.microsoft.com/windows/cse/pa_projects.mspx

Now I haven't heard of that before...only the similar sounding PREFast which I have used to statically analyse some C driver code in the past. I suspect that it's an internal Microsoft tool that no one else gets to use unless you get special access.

---

### Static Analysis Tools

A big list of static analysis tools here (e.g. FXCop).

- [What static analysis tools are available for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c)

and Typemock Racer mentioned here:

- [C#/.NET analysis tool to find race conditions/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379610/c-net-analysis-tool-to-find-race-conditions-deadlocks)

and of note is Coverity Prevent which claims to detect concurrency defects by statically analysing C/C++, Java or C# code (rated by NASA).

- http://www.verifysoft.com/en_coverity_prevent_concurrency.html
- http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/22/mars_rover_software_coverity/)

---

### WinDBG + SOSEX

Other tools to help with concurrent programming are WinDBG (part of the Windows Debugging Tools which is distributed inside the Windows SDK) which is more powerful than the Visual Studio debugger.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Note: you can now use a more powerful User Mode debugger from inside Visual Studio 2012 which has parity with WinDBG if you install the Windows Driver Kit 8 in your system.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-and-windbg-integration.aspx

You can also get plugins to WinDBG that extend it e.g. the SOSEX plugin adds the `!dlk` command which can help identify the cause of a deadlock.

- http://stevestechspot.com/
- http://blog.scriptico.com/04/debugging-with-windbg-deadlocks-in-applications/
- [Debugging a Deadlock with Windbg's !clrstack command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536465/debugging-a-deadlock-with-windbgs-clrstack-command)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/11/hang-caused-by-gc-xml-deadlock.aspx

---

### Concurrency Visualizer (in Visual Studio 2010+)

There is the Concurrency Visualizer in Visual Studio and an SDK to go with it.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2011/10/17/introducing-the-concurrency-visualizer-sdk.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336027.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee410778.aspx

---

### General Concurrent Programming Design Considerations

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc817398.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872852.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx
- http://www.packtpub.com/beginners-guide-for-C-sharp-2008-and-2005-threaded-programming/book

---

### Video Resources

Here's a brilliant series of Videos that give you general advice on debugging .NET applications:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment/Diagnosing-Application-Issues-01

Comment: None of these are static analyzers.  But yes, It is a unicorn shopping question.

Answer (score 1):

I should add:

---

### Model-Based Verification

This technique uses a formal *model* of your application's threading primitives, and tries to assert or disprove that the model has the properties that you desire, such as freedom from deadlocks.

One writes the model in a formal language, such as [Promela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promela) and then proves properties of the model using a model checker such as [Spin](http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html).

- [￼Verifying Reentrant Readers-Writers. Bernard van Gastel.](http://www.ru.nl/publish/pages/578936/bvgastelthesis.pdf)
- [Reentrant Readers-Writers – a Case Study Combining Model Checking with Theorem Proving – ICIS Technical Report R08005. Bernard van Gastel, Leonard Lensink, Sjaak Smetsers and Marko van Eekelen.](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/72239/72239.pdf?sequence=1)