# How to detect the performance issue of a multi-threaded C# application?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance

I have a multi-threaded C# application. Most of the time all the CPU cores are occupied 100%. But during a certain period, the CPU sage drop down to <30%, how can I detect what cause this?

And How can I identify the code consuming the CPU much?

Comment: Have you considered using a profiler tool?

Comment: I don't know which one to use. I am currently trying to learn one.

Comment: JetBrains dotTrace. 'Nuff said.

Comment: No, this usually requires a concurrency analyzer.  Visual Studio has a very good one, worth the price of the premium edition.

Comment: Do you want to detect what causes CPU at 30% or 100%?  If you want to detect 30% then how do you expect an application to determine the cause of a lower load?

Comment: How many threads are there in your application ? Have  you analyzed what is the code that is getting executed in each threads. Are there lots of locks on shared data and hence causing resource contention?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can set a breakpoint and use [the parallel stacks viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998398.aspx) [and here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx)

You could also create a memory dump of the process (using the task manager) and have a look at the threads in visual Studio or [open the dump in WinDBG.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

WinDBG is very useful when the process is stuck or when you want to have a look at either memory and/or [find threads that are deadlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536465/debugging-a-deadlock-with-windbgs-clrstack-command)